# HTMLCanvasElement in openlayers 3

Tags: angular, openlayers-3

I have created a canvas element as below:

```
var arrowStroke = function () {                
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            .......
            .......
            return ctx.createLinearGradient(fromx, fromy, tox, toy);
}
```

I wish to draw this canvas element created on the openlayers 3 map, but unable to do so.
I am getting only a simple LineString and not the customized one which i have created via canvaselement.

My code:

```
          var dblArrowstyle = new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                lineDash: (arrowStroke())
              })
          });
          e.feature.setStyle(dblArrowstyle);
```

I don't know how and from where to call arrowStroke() ?

Comment: I am trying to add an arrow which i have created through canvas. I just want to draw it on my openlayers 3 map, which i am not able to do.

Comment: I mean can i keep canvas element inside style of ol.feature ?